# Auto complete in text field in odoo12 using name_search

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I added a field named 'code_article' to the product and i want to use in order to choose a product in account invoice line.

I was told that the name_search method but i dont know how to use it

```
class AccountInvoiceInherited2(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice.line'
    code_article_id = fields.Char(string='code article',store=True, related='product_id.code_article')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "o choose a product in account invoice line"? Can you please explain that in more detail? Do you mean you have a new attribute on products which should be used in Odoo's (Ajax) search in Many2one fields (like in account invoice line) to not only search by `name` but also by this new attribute?

Comment: @CZoellner i mean i  added   a new attribute on product and i want  to use it  in Odoo's (Ajax) search in Many2one fields (like in account invoice line).
for example when i enter the code_article in invoice line , i want the product to be autocompleted